# No such file or directory: couldn't create child process: /opt/suphp/sbin/suphp

Tags: php, whm

This don't seems like a php memory_limit error to me, I have set CloudLinux configuration to unlimited for this website in CloudLinux LVE Manager. Any suggestion what might be causing the website 500 internal server error.

```
[Sat Sep 19 09:24:46.857537 2015] [:error] [pid 68390] (2)No such file or directory: [client 73.173.61.86:51181] couldn't create child process: /opt/suphp/sbin/suphp for /home/mywebsite/public_html/index.php
[Sat Sep 19 09:25:33.430357 2015] [:error] [pid 67875] (2)No such file or directory: [client 73.173.61.86:51191] couldn't create child process: /opt/suphp/sbin/suphp for /home/mywebsite/public_html/index.php
[Sat Sep 19 09:26:15.970405 2015] [:error] [pid 67877] (2)No such file or directory: [client 73.173.61.86:51217] couldn't create child process: /opt/suphp/sbin/suphp for /home/mywebsite/public_html/index.php
[Sat Sep 19 09:26:17.710636 2015] [:error] [pid 68390] (2)No such file or directory: [client 73.173.61.86:51218] couldn't create child process: /opt/suphp/sbin/suphp for /home/mywebsite/public_html/index.php
[Sat Sep 19 09:26:45.729530 2015] [:error] [pid 67873] (2)No such file or directory: [client 73.173.61.86:51223] couldn't create child process: /opt/suphp/sbin/suphp for /home/mywebsite/public_html/index.php
[Sat Sep 19 09:26:47.654225 2015] [:error] [pid 67874] (2)No such file or directory: [client 73.173.61.86:51224] couldn't create child process: /opt/suphp/sbin/suphp for /home/mywebsite/public_html/index.php
[Sat Sep 19 09:32:54.666577 2015] [:error] [pid 68390] (2)No such file or directory: [client 104.236.82.54:47798] couldn't create child process: /opt/suphp/sbin/suphp for /home/mywebsite/public_html/index.php
[Sat Sep 19 09:34:06.616071 2015] [:error] [pid 67874] (2)No such file or directory: [client 73.173.61.86:51328] couldn't create child process: /opt/suphp/sbin/suphp for /home/mywebsite/public_html/index.php
[Sat Sep 19 09:34:08.672377 2015] [:error] [pid 67875] (2)No such file or directory: [client 73.173.61.86:51329] couldn't create child process: /opt/suphp/sbin/suphp for /home/mywebsite/public_html/index.php
[Sat Sep 19 09:37:15.997949 2015] [:error] [pid 67875] (2)No such file or directory: [client 208.80.194.27:25675] couldn't create child process: /opt/suphp/sbin/suphp for /home/mywebsite/public_html/index.php
[Sat Sep 19 09:43:16.645956 2015] [:error] [pid 67876] (2)No such file or directory: [client 94.23.134.250:46019] couldn't create child process: /opt/suphp/sbin/suphp for /home/mywebsite/public_html/index.php
```

Comment: I received this same error, the /opt/suphp/sbin/suphp binary was actually missing. A simple restart fixed this without any further investigation needed.

Answer (score 0):

I recently found the sticky bit on the /opt/suphp/sbin/suphp file to be unset.
Adding `chmod +t /opt/suphp/sbin/suphp` will set the sticky bit back.

Alternatively `chmod 5755 /opt/suphp/sbin/suphp` will set both the sticky bit and the UID bit.